# In Java how to calculate a series of numbers to find the product, that is passed to a method that uses a variable-length argument list

Tags: java

This program is supposed to take a series of numbers, that is put into an array by the user. Not sure on how to do the calculation correctly when using the elements from the array inside of the method that I had made.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //****Sentinel****
    int s;

    //****Do...While Statement****    
    do{  

        //****User Input****
        System.out.println("Welcome! Please enter a 1 to continue, or 2 to exit.");
        s = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

    switch(s){

       case 1: 

        //****Array****
        ArrayList<Integer> nums;
        nums = new ArrayList<>();

        //****User Input****
    System.out.println("Please enter 4 integers: ");
    System.out.println("*************************************************");

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        nums.add(sc.nextInt());//****User adds to Array****

    }
    System.out.println("*************************************************");

       //****Call Method****
       Product();
       break;

       }

    }while(s != 2);//****end Do...While****
}

    //****Product Method****
    public static void Product(int... nums){

    //****variables****
    int result;
    int sum = 0;

    //****iterate through array****
    for(int n : nums){

        sum += n;
    }

    //****Multiply****
    int product = (sum * nums.length);
    result = product;


    //****User Output****  
    System.out.println("The product of the numbers is: " + result);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("*************************************************");

}
```

The only thing I get for output is a 0.

Comment: Time to use your debugger to find out why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the array to your method.

```
//****Call Method****
Product();
```

You should be passing the array there.

Comment: how do you do this?

Comment: @BroSki12: how to pass information into a method via a method parameter is Java at its most basic, and your asking this suggests that you will want to review the methods portion of most any intro to Java tutorial. Please consider checking for relevant links in the [Oracle Java Tutorial Big Index site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html).